# DES encryption and decryption using 2048 bit java

Tags: java, security, aes, rsa, des

Is there any way of encryption and decryption using DEC/ECB 2048 bit and can we generate 2048 bit key using DES.
I found that DES supports 64 bit, AES support 256 bits and If you want 2048 bit we can use RSA encryption and decryption. Also, I know that we use triple DES but it supports 168-bit encryption and decryption.

But I want to know that is it possible 2048 bit encryption and decryption Using DES.

Can anyone please suggest me on this or any different approach for this?

Comment: this might be help you, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19473/understanding-2048-bit-ssl-and-256-bit-encryption

Comment: Thanks for response @Simmant.In above link they are saying about SSL 2048 bit using RSA. I want DES 2048 bits.

Comment: With current computing power it is ridiculous to use 2048 bit keys for a symmetric cipher. You can't compare key bit length between so different algorithms like RSA and AES. To answer the question: no, DES supports only 56 bit keys (the remaining 8 bits are for parity check and don't contribute to security).

Comment: 2048/56 = 36 Digital Encryption Algorithm operations where triple DES executes the DEA 3 times (FIPS PUB 46-3 TDEA).

Comment: @user1155120 can you please share any reference link or any implementation of 3DES times (FIPS PUB 46-3 TDEA).

Comment: @BhushanW, no, please don't try to implement that as an actual crypto scheme... Use a real cipher instead, it will be more secure than anything you can invent yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
DES allows only 56-bit keys, but is insecure due to the short key.
Triple DES (3DES) is also judged insecure. (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard))
There is no provision in DES for other key lengths.

If you want a secure symmetric cipher scheme, I suggest you look into modern ciphers like [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) instead of pursuing old, insecure, ciphers.

Possibly, your demand for a bigger encryption key stems from a misunderstanding of how crypto works. SSL uses the RSA cipher because it is a good [public-key cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). This is useful in other situations than a symmetric cipher like DES. To quote Wikipedia:

> RSA is a relatively slow algorithm, and because of this, it is less commonly used to directly encrypt user data. More often, RSA passes encrypted shared keys for symmetric key cryptography which in turn can perform bulk encryption-decryption operations at much higher speed.

So, after the key exchange is done using RSA, both parties have a shared secret key which may be used for a block cipher like AES to transmit the bulk data rapidly .

Comment: **@Jolta Thanks for your awesome response.** I know DES is insecure but I just want to know that is there any way or provision in DES to user 2048 key length.